# If you are compiling for a jailbroken iPhone, what core should you target? Specifically with an iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, arm, boinc

If you are compiling for a jailbroken iPhone, what core needs to be targetted?  Specifically with an iPhone 4s.  I assume that compiling against the Cortex-A9 would be safe, but would love to hear any thoughts on this.

I'm looking to compile BOINC for iOS and would like to test this.  Eventually I plan to try to submit an official grid computing app to the App Store, but believe that some "under the hood" trial and error is due first.

Answer (score 1):

The A5 is armv7, while the A6 in the iPhone 5 is armv7s